# No nodes discovered

Tags: ansible, rundeck

I don't see any nodes from Ansible hosts file in a test Rustdeck environment (running on Rocky 9).

So far I've tried moving all the files to separate folder with 777 permissions. Also tried:

```
rundeck -c "ansible all -m ping"
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit
localhost does not match 'all'
```

The hosts file currently located at /rundeck/Ansible_EMS_samples/inventory/hosts.yaml looks like this:

```yaml
virtualmachines:
  hosts:
    linux_opensuse_leap:
      ansible_host: 192.168.10.149
  vars:
    ansible_user: admin

win_px:
  hosts:
    w11-ansible-1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.10.181
    w11-ansible-2:
      ansible_host: 192.168.10.182
  vars:
    ansible_user: admin
    ansible_password: somepassword1234
    ansible_connection: ssh
    ansible_shell_type: powershell
```

The nodes are set in Project Settings -> Edit nodes:

[image: nodes setup]

Any ideas what else can I try to make it work?

Comment: Hi! Turn off the gather facts (on the Ansible Resource Model Source) and try again.

Comment: @MegaDrive68k : oh, that was unexpected - without "gather facts" it works! I wonder why?

Comment: In some inventories, the plugin has problems gathering facts, probably related: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/ansible-plugin/issues/155 Let me add the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off the "Gather facts" on the Model Source solves some inventory facts problems and enables the most basic way to access the Ansible nodes on Rundeck. Issue [related](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/ansible-plugin/issues/155).